# "This webpage is unavailable" when running Jekyll locally on Cloud9

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jekyll, cloud9-ide

I'm trying to setup Jekyll on Cloud9 IDE and then run locally but i keep getting a page that says "This webpage is not available".

Following instructions on 'https://rubygems.org/gems/jekyll/versions/3.0.1' and https://jekyllrb.com/, here's what i've done.

1. Added gem in gemfile (gem 'jekyll', '~> 3.0', '>= 3.0.1').
2. > bundle install

Everthing looks like it installs fine.

3. > gem install jekyll

'Successfully installed jekyll-3.0.1'.

4. > jekyll new blog

'New jekyll site installed in /home/ubuntu/workspace/blog.'.

5. > cd blog
6. > jekyl serve

The page that loads is 'This webpage is not available.'

7. > jekyll serve -p $PORT -b $IP

Same result.

8. > jekyll s -p $PORT -b $IP

Same result.

Normally when i want to run locally i just do "rails s -p $PORT -b $IP".
Not really sure how to get this to work. I'm still kindof new to ruby on rails so apologies if i'm missing something simple here.

Thankyou!

Comment: Does this help: https://docs.c9.io/docs/jekyll

Comment: @Mutahhier. Thanks! That worked. I should have found that myself...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved.

Thanks @Matahhir for providing this link in the comments above.

https://docs.c9.io/docs/jekyll

I needed to run,

> jekyll serve --host $IP --port $PORT --baseurl ""

Answer (score 0):

Here is a how-to for installing Jekyll on Cloud9:

1. create a free account on Cloud9 (https://c9.io)
2. create an empty project (Ubuntu) and follow these steps:
3. type on the command line: gem install jekyll
4. create an empty _config.yml file in the root
5. create a index.md file in the root
6. type on the command line: jekyll serve --host $IP --port $PORT --baseurl ''
7. your website is now running 'locally' on Cloud9

The content of your index.md file:

```
---
title: Home
---

Hello world!
```